# ~/.pam_environment login problem

Tags: login, environment-variables

I added `$PATH` to `~/.pam_environment` file but after that I can not login.

It seems setting was not OK.

Now I'd like to change `~/.pam_environment` to its original shape but I could not find it.
I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to login as root and now I do not know where to find that file.

I use Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either login as your own user in the TTY, or if you have to use root, use your username as part of the path (assuming `mahdi` is your username):

```
nano ~mahdi/.pam_environment
```

Or, probably equivalent:

```
nano /home/mahdi/.pam_environment
```

Otherwise `~` will refer to the root user's home directory, not yours.

Comment: Hi Muru,Thanks a lot , It exactly resolves the problem. .pam_environment file is in /home/mahdi/ directory. I could find it by "ls -a" command.